# How to bind gridview to a wcf service application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I want to bind my gridview based on the retrieved data from wcf service .But it shows only last row data in gridview instead of showing them all.

Here is my  WCF:

```
try
{
  DSCustomer dscat = new DSCustomer();
   //input is EmpUserID
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myuser", id);
   cmd.CommandText = "mystoredproc";
   List<DSCustomer> lst = new List<DSCustomer>();
   SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   while (dr.Read())
   {
      dscat.MyEmpID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Emp"]);
      dscat.MyEmpName = dr["EmpName"].ToString();
      dscat.MyUnitName = dr["UnitName"].ToString();
      dscat.MyUnitNumber = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Unit"]);
      dscat.MyRole = dr["Role"].ToString();
      dscat.MySurveyStatus = dr["SurveyStatus"].ToString();

      //Add all the returns in to the list from back-end
      lst.Add(dscat);
   }

   //returns to the list
   return lst;
}
```

this is DScustomer

```
public class DSCustomer
    {
        //Created properties based on the count of the data that we want to retrieve
        public int MyEmpID { get; set; }
        public string MyEmpName { get; set; }
        public string MyUnitName { get; set; }
        public int MyUnitNumber { get; set; }
        public string MyRole { get; set; }
        public string MySurveyStatus { get; set; }

    }
```

And my default.aspx:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();
   Customer cust = new Customer();

   cust = client.getCategori(tbEmpID.Text);

   var list = new List<Customer> { cust };
   GridView1.DataSource=list;
   GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Stupid question. Is this the real code for the service? I don't see any place in the while loop instantiating a new instance of whatever dscat is. So the values will get overriden each time.

Comment: Don be like that please . Just share you answer , I didnt share this question to hear your slung .

Comment: @Abdullah what is the WCF method signature and What is the `client.getCategori` return type ?

Comment: I wasn't being rude, sometimes people post something that is close to the actual code, but is not actually the real code. "Stupid question" was referring to MY question, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

problem is I think you calling different service

```
Customer cust = new Customer();
cust = client.getCategori(tbEmpID.Text); // this method only return one customer 
var list = new List<Customer> { cust };
GridView1.DataSource=list;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

In your given service you are returning List so you can directly bind it to DataGrid

```
GridView1.DataSource=client.getCategori(tbEmpID.Text).AsEnumerable() ;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

One more thing, inside while loop create new `DSCustomer` and add it to list at the end

```
   while (dr.Read())
   {
      DSCustomer cust = new DSCustomer();
      cust.MyEmpID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Emp"]);
      cust.MyEmpName = dr["EmpName"].ToString();
      cust.MyUnitName = dr["UnitName"].ToString();
      cust.MyUnitNumber = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Unit"]);
      cust.MyRole = dr["Role"].ToString();
      cust.MySurveyStatus = dr["SurveyStatus"].ToString();
      lst.Add(cust);
   }
```

Comment: IT is based on empid. when i run it in back-end , shows me two records.

Comment: I tried that way but shows me  Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource. error

Comment: @Abdullah try with `.AsEnumerable()` at the end

Comment: It is not working  . :(   , same thing happens while try to bind your Dropdowsnlist . What is the key point ?  ,

Comment: Do you have WCF and ASP.Net projects in same solution? start both at same time and put brak point on service. click the button and call the service from ASP.net see what is the value of WCF service retutning from service side and check from asp.net side also.

Comment: I debug it , it takes 2 counts inside the list but shows only one row in gridview

Answer (score 0):

The line where you declare the dscat variable:

```
DSCustomer dscat = new DSCustomer();
```

Should be moved inside of the while loop.  While you might be adding N number of elements to lst, each DSCustomer item in lst will have the same values as last item added to the lst list.

Also note that your call to the WCF service:

```
Customer cust = new Customer();
cust = client.getCategori(tbEmpID.Text);
```

Shows that you will only get 1 customer object back (not many), and then you create a list of 1 item from that object:

```
var list = new List<Customer> { cust }; // list only has 1 item.
```

So it seems that the code you show for the WCF service is not the same method that you are calling on the client.